# Eclipse Export JAR, not able to select resource

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I created a java project in eclipse helios. Ubuntu. When i try to export Jar file, not able to select resources. Please find attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. Reinstalled eclipse and started using vm screen in full screen mode.